# Launch script with combination of arguments

Tags: bash, permutation

I am running some test and I need to run a particolar shell script with the combination of some input.

Let's suppose I have the script `test.sh` that takes 3 arguments: A, B, C.

And A can be 1 or 2, B can be "aa" or "bb" and C can be 7 or 8

I would like to automatically launch all the possible combination, so

```
./test 1 "aa" 7
./test 1 "aa" 8
./test 1 "bb" 7
./test 1 "bb" 8
./test 2 "aa" 7
./test 2 "aa" 8
./test 2 "bb" 7
./test 2 "bb" 8
```

There is something already ready and tested ?

EDIT: permutation -> combination

Comment: This combinations, not permutations. Permutations means you change the order of a list of things, like `a b c`, `a c b`, `b a c`, etc.

Comment: thank you :) i edited the question.

Answer (score 3):

A somewhat ugly (ab)use of shell brace expansion allows for this:

```
$ for i in {1,2}\ {aa,bb}\ {7,8}; do
    echo {$i}
done
{1 aa 7}
{1 aa 8}
{1 bb 7}
{1 bb 8}
{2 aa 7}
{2 aa 8}
{2 bb 7}
{2 bb 8}
```

but this only works if the individual values **do not** contain spaces or shell/glob metacharacters.

If they can contain either of those then this isn't safe and should be avoided.

Comment: @chepner Thanks but the bracing was as intended. The point was to show the grouping of the entries. (I almost added `printf '[%s]\n'` to show how they are separate words but thought that would be overkill.)

Comment: Oh, sorry. That's what I get for making such a minor-seeming correction in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

You could use 3 for loops :

```
for x in 1 2; do
  for y in "aa" "bb"; do
    for z in 7 8; do
      ./test $x $y $z
    done
  done
done
```

> Test run :
>
> ```
> $ for x in 1 2; do
> >   for y in "aa" "bb"; do
> >     for z in 7 8; do
> >       echo $x $y $z
> > done;done;done
> 1 aa 7
> 1 aa 8
> 1 bb 7
> 1 bb 8
> 2 aa 7
> 2 aa 8
> 2 bb 7
> 2 bb 8
> ```

Now there may be a way to condense them in a single for loop, you might want to wait for another answer if that's your wish.